# unique_ptr: So I can't reference to a deleted function anymore

Tags: c++

I have 2 classes and I would like to return a reference to a private member object.

```
class BB{};

class B
{
   std::unique_ptr<BB> b;
public:
   const std::unique_ptr<BB>& getBB(){return b;} 
};
int main()
{
   B b;
   std::unique_ptr<BB> x=b.getBB();
}
```

Undoubtedly, the error occurs in main at `x=b.GetBB()` that says 
`...can't be referenced. It's a deleted function.`

Comment: Can you please post the complete error?

Comment: Leaving `std::unique_ptr<BB> b;` uninitialized does not a default-constructed `BB` make btw, unless you left out `B`'s constructor.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to copy initialize `unique_ptr`, that is not allowed, since `unique_ptr` has deleted copy constructor. Try

```
const std::unique_ptr<BB>& x = b.getBB();
```

Comment: Thank you, it works, I will make it a constant reference from now